# setwd() in the current working dir

Tags: r

I have a list of folders. In each folder there's an R identical script that have to run on files into the folder. I wrote the script one time and copied the script in each folder. The problem is that I have  a list of around 100 folders so it is impossible to me to setwd() in the current working dir by hand. I would like to know if it is possible to set current working dir with for example a "." in this way:

```
setwd("/User/myname/./")
```

or in another easy way that tells R the current working dir instead of typing every time the folder name.

Comment: Why did you copy an identical script in each folder and why do you need to set the working directory? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Why not just have one script and perform its contents for each folder? Say through a loop?

Comment: Hi Roland and sebastian! It is just because I start from a very big matrix (around 2.8G) so I divided it in subfolders and in each folder I run the same script because I have to do the same operations on the files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

how about this?

```
# set the working directory to the main folder containing all the directories
setwd( "/user/yourdir/" )

# pull all files and folders (including subfolders) into a character vector
# keep ONLY the files that END with ".R" or ".r"
r.scripts <- list.files( pattern=".*\\.[rR]$" , recursive = TRUE )

# look at the contents.. now you've got just the R scripts..
# i think that's what you want?
r.scripts

# and you can loop through and source() each one
for ( i in r.scripts ) source( i )
```

Comment: You might be interested in the `pattern` argument to `list.files`.

Comment: If the OP wants to loop through folders and set the working directories to them, they might want to consider `list.dirs(recursive=FALSE)` if they're all one level deep.

Comment: Hi Antony, yes it is what i want more or less.

Comment: You might also want `chdir = T` in `source`

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, you want to trigger a batch of R scripts, where the scripts are distributed across a number of folders.

Personally, I would probably write a shell script (or OS equivilent) to do this, rather than doing it in R.

```
for dir in /directoriesLocation/*/
do
    cat $dir/scriptName.R | R --slave --args $arg1 $arg2
done
```

where **$dir** is the the location of all directories containing the R script **scriptName.R**

Comment: Hi! Yes, I run a .sh script that call a .bash script to run all the .R script since I'm working on cluster.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other great answers the `source` function has a `chdir` argument that will temporarily change the working directory to the one that the sourced file is in.

One option would be to create a vector with the filenames (including paths) for each of your script files, using `list.files` and/or other tools.  Then `source` each of those files and letting `source` with `chdir` handle setting the working directory for you.