# How to set the current file location as the default working directory in R programming?

Tags: r, setwd

I want to make the current file location as the working directory.

**Using Rstudio (Works!):**

```
# Author  : Bhishan Poudel
# Program : writehere.r
# Source  : Rscript writehere.r

# set working directory here
this.dir <- dirname(parent.frame(2)$ofile) # frame(3) also works.
setwd(this.dir)

# Sample data to test this code
mydata <- seq(1:10)
write.csv(mydata,"writehere.dat")
#This works flawlessly in  MacOS 10.9 and Ubuntu 15.1.
```

**Using Command from terminal :   Rscript writehere.r (Does not work!)**

```
Error in dirname(parent.frame(2)$ofile) : 
  a character vector argument expected
Execution halted


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
```

**Using Command from terminal :   Rscript writehere.r (Works now!)**

```
# Author  : Bhishan Poudel
# Program : writehere.r
# Source  : Rscript example.r

# set working directory here
this_dir <- function(directory)
setwd( file.path(getwd(), directory) )

# Sample data to test this code
mydata <- seq(1:10)
write.csv(mydata,"writehere.dat")
```

**Using function inside ~/.Rprofile for Rstudio (Works!) :**,

```
##############################################
# inside ~/.Rprofile
# set up working directory
setwd_thisdir <- function () {
  this.dir <- dirname(parent.frame(3)$ofile)
  setwd(this.dir)
} 
##############################################
```

Then, in any directory let's say I have a file writehere.r, now it works.

```
# Author  : Bhishan Poudel
# Program : writehere.r
# Compile : Rscript writehere.r

# set working directory here
setwd_thisdir

# Sample data to test this code
mydata <- seq(1:10)
write.csv(mydata,"writehere.dat")
```

**Question:**
Why the function

```
this.dir <- dirname(parent.frame(2)$ofile) # frame(3) also works.
setwd(this.dir)
```

does not work for text editors other than Rstudio?

Some useful links are following:
[R setting working directory to source file location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34843889/r-setting-working-directory-to-source-file-location)
[R command for setting working directory to source file location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672720/r-command-for-setting-working-directory-to-source-file-location?rq=1)
 [get filename and path of `source`d file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835426/get-filename-and-path-of-sourced-file)
[setwd() in the current working dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026463/setwd-in-the-current-working-dir)
[Command for "Set working directory to source file location"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519172/command-for-set-working-directory-to-source-file-location?rq=1)
[SublimeText and R: Setting Current File Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732597/sublimetext-and-r-setting-current-file-directory?rq=1)
[Setting working directory through a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23107094/setting-working-directory-through-a-function?rq=1)
[What is a fool-proof way of permanently setting R working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433559/what-is-a-fool-proof-way-of-permanently-setting-r-working-directory?rq=1)
[R setting working directory to source file location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34843889/r-setting-working-directory-to-source-file-location?rq=1)
[How to get into the directory of a file in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35523730/how-to-get-into-the-directory-of-a-file-in-r?rq=1)

Comment: what is `class(parent.frame(2)$ofile)`?

Comment: @MichaelChirico I don't know, I followed the suggestion from the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34843889/r-setting-working-directory-to-source-file-location

Comment: add the line `print(class(parent.frame(2)$ofile))` and try running your function.l

Comment: @MichaelChirico answer is  "NULL"

Comment: @MichaelChirico when I run the function in the example.r, it works perfectly, but when I put it inside .Rprofile and invoke it from example.r, it does not work!

Comment: I'm surprised it works in the first place -- I don't have any `ofile` in my `R_GlobalEnv`

Comment: @MichaelChirico I can attach screenprint if you desire, I am also surprised, print(class(parent.frame(2)$ofile)) gives "NULL", and given function setwd_thisdir works fine inside exampl.r but not if it is inside .Rprofile. If you could provide some function that works in .Rprofile, that is what i am looking for!!

Comment: @jenesaisquoi, yes there is a command "Rscript" to source ".r" files . If I have "example.r" file, to source it I type "Rscript example.r" in the shell and it gives the results.

Comment: For clarification, all methods here work only for a file that is `source`d or passed to `RScript`. There seems to be no way to determine the file (or that file's directory) which is currently ran line by line (Ctrl+R). And how should R know? In that case, code is passed line by line to the interpreter - no file involved. However, RStudio knows which file is currently active, but IMHO there's currently no way to exploit this.

Comment: To add some further clarification: `ofile` is a variable defined in the `source` function (`View( source )` to view its code), so the '`parent.frame(n)$ofile`' works if you use this function to source the script. On the other side if you use `RScript`, then the working directory is set to your current directory in the teminal, so if you run `Rscript writehere.r` you don't need to change the working directory.

Answer (score 10):

Simply, use rstudio API, extract its directory, and set it as a working directory as shown below:

```
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path))
```

Verify if you set the directory correctly by the following command:

```
getwd()
```

Answer (score 2):

I write another answer because you changed your question. There are two useful facts:

1. `ofile` is a variable in the environment of the `source` function, so you can use it only when you run some script with the `source` function.
2. When you run a script from the terminal, then the working directory is set to the current directory in the terminal.

So, to comment on your observations:

1. Using Rstudio (Works!). Yes if you press *Source* (which usues the `source` function), but not if you press *Run* (which just runs the commands in the R console).
2. Rscript writehere.r (Does not work!). That's because you are looking for `ofile` without a call to `source`.
3. Rscript writehere.r (Works now!). Yes, but it works just by *fact 2*: the code `this_dir <- function(directory) setwd( file.path(getwd(), directory) )` is needless as it is just the definition of a function called `this_dir`.
4. Rstudio (Works!). First part: OK. Second part. It works just by *fact 2*. In particular `setwd_thisdir` is needless because it just prints the body of `setwd_thisdir` to the console.

In summary `setwd(dirname(parent.frame(2)$ofile))` is a useful trick when you source a script with the `source` function, but don't have access to the `source` function options: e.g. when you press *Source* in R-Studio. When possible use intead the `source` function with `chdir=TRUE`. If you run the script form the terminal just set the terminal to the script folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `parent.frame(3)` in you function:

```
setwd_thisdir <- function () {
  this.dir <- dirname(parent.frame(3)$ofile)
  setwd(this.dir)
}
```

See `?parent.frame` or http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html#calling-environments.

You may also look at the `chdir` option of the `source` function (`?source`).

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I realised that this answer didn't help at all, and I will post another one that does the trick.

Insofar the code you want to run doesn't need any additional arguments, a solution as sketched below, using `eval(expr, envir)` might do the trick.

Consider the following example using `print(environment())`, which should return `environment: R_GlobalEnv` when used on the command line.  The function `test_1` will print information about the internal environment that is created when the function is called, whereas the function `test_2` will return the desired result.

```
test_1 <- function(){
     print(environment())
}

test_2 <- function(){
    .expr <- quote({
        print(environment())
        })
    .envir <- sys.frame(which = -1)
    eval(expr = .expr,
         envir = .envir)
}
```

The `sys.frame(which = -1)` ensures that the expression is evaluated in the environment where the function is called.  If you are certain that you always want to use the global environment, then it's better to use `.GlobalEnv`.  It's also important to quote the expression you want to use, otherwise it might not work as desired.

A nice feature of this solution is that you don't need to tweak the code you want to put into the function, just quote it.

Finally: It's possible to extend this approach such that your function can take arguments that then will be given to the code you want to evaluate in another environment.  This will however require a bit of non-trivial tweaking upon the expression you want to evaluate; you might need to use the `bquote` + `.()` construction - and you might in addition also need to use `call` and `do.call`.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer I gave missed the point completely, since I hadn't
looked closely upon what you wanted to achieve.  The solution
presented here should however do the trick.

First note that `source` has an argument `chdir` that in the help-file is described with: logical; if `TRUE` and `file` is a pathname, the R working directory is temporarily changed to the directory containing `file` for evaluating.

To manually specify that argument every time you want to source a file
would be a pain, so let's add something to .Rprofile that changes the
default value for `chdir` from `FALSE` to `TRUE`.

The `formals`-function can be used to modify a default
value, but when used upon a function that belongs to some other
environment, the result will be that a local copy of the function will be created instead. That's not good enough.

It's probably several ways to resolve this, but the following
little hack of `source` did the trick for me when I inserted it into .Rprofile.

```
.temporary_copy_source <- base::source
formals(.temporary_copy_source)$chdir <- TRUE
utils::assignInNamespace(
    x = "source",
    value = .temporary_copy_source,
    ns = environment(source))
rm(.temporary_copy_source)
```

**A word of warning:** The method presented here can in principle
allow users to modify the default values of any argument in any
function, but that would be an exceptionally bad idea to do. Keep
in mind that your scripts might later on be shared with someone
that doesn't have the same .Rprofile that you have.  **Never write
code that requires such modifications of the namespaces!**